# Can we create an object without parentheses?

Tags: java, arrays, object, syntax, new-operator

According to [this site](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/new) the syntax for creating a Java object is:

```
<JavaType> <variable> = new <JavaObject>();
```

Though you don't use any parantheses when creating an Array object and instead type brackets which contains the length of each dimension.

Example:

```
String[][] stringMatrix = new String[5][10];
```

What I am wondering is if this syntax is specifically and only for creating an Array object or I can make a custom class whose objects are created in a different way then usual

```
new <JavaObject>();
```

statement.

Comment: The page you linked to is evidently not a great resource.

Comment: there are set of rules in all language on how you can create object and array or declaring any variable. Same in java. I'm not sure, what specifically you are looking for

Comment: Why are you looking for a different way of doing things? What's wrong with the way you know? It's not like it complex or overly long.

Comment: i just wondered if it is possible using the language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`new` keyword is used to allocate memory for the specific type***, which is followed by `new` keyword.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

Above line will create an object (allocate memory) for `MyClass` and initialize member variable by invoking default constructor.

But, below line of code will only allocate memory and initialize each element of array with default value `null`.

```
MyClass[][] objMatrix = new MyClass[5][10];
```

So, we are just declaring an array of size `5x10`(allocating memory), but each element in array need some object reference (since, currently they have `null` reference). So, for that reason, you need to initialize each `objMatrix`  array element by creating object of `MyClass` and assigning them to each element.

```
objMatrix[0][0] = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is specifically for creating arrays. You're stuck with parentheses for your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a custom class that changes the way the `new` operator works. However, there are some special cases where an object can be created without the usual `new` operator.

E.g.

```
String[] array = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
Integer value = 42;
```

demonstrating that you can create arrays without the `new` keyword in a variable initializer, use `String` objects using literals and autobox primitive values to their object counterpart without the usual `new` syntax, but of course, this is not possible with custom types.

Another possibility to create objects without the `new` operator is deserializing them, which also works for custom types if they are `Serializable`.

Starting with Java 8, you can use constructor references if you have an appropriate context, e.g.

```
BigDecimal[] array = new BigDecimal[20];
Arrays.setAll(array, BigDecimal::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Here, `BigDecimal::new` is a reference to a constructor of `BigDecimal` and it is implied from the context, i.e. `Arrays.setAll` that the function must be able to consume an `int` value, as the `setAll` method will evaluate it for every array element, passing the array index, so we initialize the array with ascending numbers in this example.

Another example would be

```
BigDecimal[] array = Stream.of("1.23", "4.56", "7.89")
                           .map(BigDecimal::new)
                           .toArray(BigDecimal[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

where it is implied from the context that the constructor used in the `.map(BigDecimal::new)` step must consume a `String`, as it will be evaluated for every stream element, ending up at a different constructor than in the first example.

`BigDecimal` is an ordinary class and these examples would work with a custom class as well, if it has matching constructors.